# How to count and compare in Django

Tags: python, django

Currently have a database with 10 questions which posts a number from 1-4 i just want to add that number up to create a total then only show the closest match for that total number 
**Models.py**

```
class Question(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
question1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Question1_CHOICES)
question2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Question2_CHOICES)
question3 = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Question3_CHOICES)
question4 = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Question4_CHOICES)
question5 = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Question5_CHOICES)
question6 = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Question6_CHOICES)
question7 = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Question7_CHOICES)
question8 = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Question8_CHOICES)
question9 = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Question9_CHOICES)
question10 = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Question10_CHOICES)
```

Views.py

```
def comparison(request):
    return render(request, 'music/compare.html', dict(rows=Question.objects.all(), total=Question.objects.count()))
```

I tried using total with count but I don't think its correct. 
Copy of database layout attached [image: here]

Edit - Addded compare.html

```
    {% extends 'music/index.html' %}
{% block body %}

<body>
    <table>
    <table>
    <th>
    <tr>
    <table border="3">
        {% for row in rows %}
    <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
    <td>Question 1 </td>
    <td>Question 2 </td>
    <td>Question 3 </td>
    <td>Question 4 </td>
    <td>Question 5 </td>
    <td>Question 6 </td>
    <td>Question 7 </td>
    <td>Question 8 </td>
    <td>Question 9 </td>
    <td>Question 10 </td>
    <td>Total </td>
  </tr>
  </th>

  <tr>
    <td>{{row.name}} </td>
    <td>{{row.question1}} </td>
    <td>{{row.question2}} </td>
    <td>{{row.question3}} </td>
    <td>{{row.question4}} </td>
    <td>{{row.question5}} </td>
    <td>{{row.question6}} </td>
    <td>{{row.question7}} </td>
    <td>{{row.question8}} </td>
    <td>{{row.question9}} </td>
    <td>{{row.question10}} </td>
    <td>{{ question.s }} </td>
  </tr>
     </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    </body>
{%endblock%
```

}

Comment: Hmmmm. Can you be more specific about what you ask?

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in char fields 50 characters long? You are probably looking for the Sum function.

Comment: This can all be changed it was get the idea that it works. Can you explain the Sum function please I've not used it.

Comment: @nik_m What more would you like to know? I thought i was detailed, please let me know

Comment: so you want a QuerySet with 10 values, the sum of each question. For example: `[999+3, 2+2, 2+2, ...]` ?

Comment: Close, More i want to combine the total of questions 1 through 10 and then display that overall total  so  1,3,4,5 ... = 13 if that makes sense?

Comment: Could you please **edit your question with both the current HTML and views** ?

Comment: I did, It's stating that it needs to be peer reviewed for the changes occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the sum of `Question1` through `Question10` for each row then do this:

```
from django.db.models import F

questions = Question.objects.annotate(s=F('question1') + F('question2') + F('question3') + F('question4') + F('question5') + F('question6') + F('question7') + F('question8') + F('question9') + F('question10'))
```

This will produce `x` number of results equal to the number of rows.
Then you can do:

```
for question in questions:
    print(question.s)  # prints the sum of Question1 - Question10
```

Or, if you just want the values (not `Question` objects) then:

```
sums = Question.objects.annotate(s=F('question1') + F('question2') + F('question3') + F('question4') + F('question5') + F('question6') + F('question7') + F('question8') + F('question9') + F('question10')).values('s')
```

[UPDATE]: It seems you are not looping correctly the `questions` `QuerySet`.

Here is what you have to do:

in your `views.py` have it like this:

```
questions = Question.objects.annotate(s=F('question1') + F('question2') + F('question3') + F('question4') + F('question5') + F('question6') + F('question7') + F('question8') + F('question9') + F('question10'))

...

return render(request, 'music/compare.html', {'questions': questions})
```

And then then in your HTML have it like this:

```
{% for question in questions %}
    <td>Question 1 </td>
    ...
    <td>{{question.name}} </td>
    ...
    <td>{{ question.s }} </td>
```

**Edit 2 - changed views.py**

```
def compare():
    questions = Question.objects.annotate(
        s=F('question1') + F('question2') + F('question3') + F('question4') + F('question5') + F('question6') + F(
            'question7') + F('question8') + F('question9') + F('question10'))

    ...

    return render(request, 'music/compare.html', {'questions': questions})
```

**compare.html**

```
{% for question in questions %}
    <td>Question 1 </td>
    ...
    <td>{{question.name}} </td>
    ...
    <td>{{ question.s }} </td>

{%endfor%}
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for this i'll look into it can i ask why you didn't use Count or Sum to work this out?

Comment: It depends on what you want. The `Count` counts rows (not values inside of rows). Yes, I could have used `Sum` but in this case it's reduntant. Usually, you use `Sum` when you have slightly complex computations, like this: `Sum(F('question1')/F('question2'))`, which computes the sum of the division of all rows (it'll return a single value)

Comment: how would you display this in a HTML document?

Comment: im not sure how you call this in HTML how would you make it display?

Comment: First you can name the allias `s` whatever you like. I just named it `s` from the word "sum". Now that you have your `questions` `QuerySet`, inside the HTML call each sum like that: `{% for q in questions %}{{ q.s }}{% endfor %}`

Comment: It doesn't seem to be displaying anything, any idea why?

Comment: Runsever does run in shell, but on the HTMLside it  fails to show anything

Comment: this is all i get back from the server when the page is requested
[15/Mar/2017 13:36:50] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 2772

Comment: Are you rendering `questions` in the template via the `render` method?

Comment: Yes i am this is being done by {{row.question}} like you showed earlier, But this wont display  My definition is currently like this 

def compare():
    questions=Question.objects.annotate(
        s=F('question1') + F('question2') + F('question3') + F('question4') + F('question5') + F(
        'question6') + F('question7') + F('question8') + F('question9') + F('question10'))
    return render(request, 'music/compare.html'

Comment: Thanks for that nik_m It threw a end for error at me so i did {% endfor %} to fix it, but it is still not displaying anything which i just dont understand!!!

Comment: It seems you haven't done anything. I'm getting tired... Both `views.py` **and** HTML

Comment: Sorry for the trouble im causing you nik_m, i assure you I've made these changes. All it prints is a white HTML page